# C# Address Book GUI not closing

Tags: c#, user-interface, formclosing

Alright so I figured out my EXTREMELY stupid mistake about why the folders weren't being created but there was another problem I was having. Whenever I try to close the Window Application it wont close. It's suppose to save the information that is in the file but it doesn't and it wont close either.

```
    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
        xDoc.Load(path + "\\Address Book\\settings.xml");
        XmlNode xNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("People");
        xNode.RemoveAll();
        foreach (Person p in people)
        {
            XmlNode xTop = xDoc.CreateElement("Person");
            XmlNode xName = xDoc.CreateElement("Name");
            XmlNode xEmail = xDoc.CreateElement("Email");
            xName.InnerText = p.Name;
            xEmail.InnerText = p.Email;
            xTop.AppendChild(xName);
            xTop.AppendChild(xEmail);
            xDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xTop);
        }
        xDoc.Save(path + "\\Address Book\\settings.xml");
    }
```

That's what I have right now.

Comment: Does it close when you comment out the code inside the `Form1_FormClosing` method?

Comment: Yes, if I remove the FormClosing entirely it will close.

Comment: OK, and did you try stepping through the code to see where it blocks up?

Comment: It seems to be that the xml doesn't want to load the xml or save the xml.

Comment: So the issue is occurring on the last line when you call `xDoc.Save`? It freezes there?

Comment: Well it doesn't Freeze....It just doesn't save and then it doesn't close either.

Comment: So there are two problems here and I'm not exactly sure why you think the not-closing issue is a result of the not-saving-xml-files issue.